# Average the results from a function over many objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, aggregate

I'm trying to calculate stats on the trades in my model. These stats are mainly derived using functions inside my trade model. I've listed all the stats that are so far working and right now I'm stuck on calculating the Avg "win" value and percent.

Thanks for the help SOF community!

views.py

```
class StatsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        trade = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='cl')
        context = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        #ALL WORKING STATS
        context['all_trades'] = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
        context['gross_profit'] = sum([t.get_profit_loss_value() for t in trade])
        context['net_profit'] = sum([t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade])
        context['win_trades_profit'] = sum(t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade if t.get_trade_result() == 'win')
        context['loss_trades_profit'] = sum(t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade if t.get_trade_result() == 'loss')
        context['win_trades_count'] = sum(t.get_trade_result() == 'win' for t in trade)
        #context['win_trades_count'] = [t.get_trade_result() for t in trade].count('win') ALSO WORKS
        context['loss_trades_count'] = sum(t.get_trade_result() == 'loss' for t in trade)
        context['scratch_trades_count'] = sum(t.get_trade_result() == 'scratch' for t in trade)
        context['total_fees'] = sum([t.get_fees() for t in trade])

        #NOT WORKING YET
        #Calculate Avg Profit For All Winning Trades

        #Result: Avg(Value(<generator object StatsView.get_context_data.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002C98818F3C8>))

        #context['avg_win'] = Avg(t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade if t.get_trade_result() == 'win')
```

models.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='cl')
    ...

    # profit_loss_value_fees = profit_loss_value - fees
    def get_profit_loss_value_fees(self):
        result = self.get_profit_loss_value() - self.get_fees()
        return result

class Entry(models.Model):
    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price/fee/amount/entry_type/etc...
```

---

*Little follow-up bonus question, just in case someone has some ideas as I'm stuck on this part as well.*

I need to start filtering the stats after this. How would you guys recommend to incorporate a very dynamic filtering system to these stats? Everything from date to which portfolio the trades belong too.

---

Answer to the original problem. It was very simple..

```
context['avg_win'] = mean(t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade if t.get_trade_result() == 'win')
```

Would still appreciate ideas on the filtering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() == 'win' for t in trade` returns an iterable like `[True, True, False, ...]` depending on whether `t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() == 'win'`.

If so you can do the following:

```py
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # ...

    plvf = [t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() == 'win' for t in trade]
    context['avg_win'] = plvf.count(True)/len(plvf)

    # or more simply (importing statistics)
    context['avg_win'] = statistics.mean([t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() == 'win' for t in trade])
```

Comment: I just identified a giant mistake on my end get_profit_loss_value_fees() returns a float and not a string. I have left only Test 2 as although it's not working it's the one that does not make the mistake, also if "Avg" was changed to "sum" it would give an answer, just give the wrong answer.

Comment: This is the answer: context['avg_win'] = mean(t.get_profit_loss_value_fees() for t in trade if t.get_trade_result() == 'win') .... I was looking at this problem for way to long and just remembering that I was printing a list reminded me I just needed to use simple math to get the solution. I was too focused on the error message which I didn't not understand. Thanks for the attempt at the answer it made me see what was right in front of me and for that I'll mark it as right and add the solution to my question. Thanks again and stay safe!